# What cleats should I get as my first cycling shoes?

Tags: pedals, shoes

In September I got a Scott CR1 (2007 model) for my 17th birthday.  It's my first road bike and I love commuting on it.

Up until I got my Scott I was a strict mountain biker.  So when I got my road bike I got a pair of mountain bike pedals for it since I already had the shoes.

Now, after 3k miles or so, my pedals are really wearing themselves out.  I want to get a pair of road bike cleats.  But which ones should I start with?  I don't want the "entry line" cleats but I also don't want to spend more than $150 MAX.

[This](http://www.shimano.com/publish/content/global_cycle/en/au/index/products/road/ultegra/product.-code-PD-6700-G.-type-..html) is what I was thinking about for the pedals and cleats.

[This](https://www.serfas.com/products/view/8/referer%3aproducts%7Cindex%7Cshoes%7Cmens-road-shoes) is what I had in mind for shoes.

Comment: Could you clarify what's your specific question? It sounds like you're asking for what's the most durable cleat, but the question isn't quite specific enough to know for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, looks good, sounds like you already know what you want. If you get those items you mentioned, you'll be able to pedal your bike.

Why are you spending money to switch cleat styles? I'm assuming you had clipless pedals on the mountain bike as well.  Unless you're having issues with your existing cleats, I'd just buy all my gear to match.  I happily use SPD pedals on both my road and mountain bike, so do lots of other people.

I use MTB shoes on my road bike and like them because they are not awkward to walk around in compared to SPD-SL cleats on road shoes. However, you could easily get a separate pair of 'road' shoes that use the same style cleat, then you could use the shoes interchangeably depending on what you're doing (I'd prefer the mountain shoes when touring or urban riding, while the road shoes may feel better for longer road rides with infrequent stopping).

However, if you have issues with your current setup (like hot spots on the feet), not feeling as firmly clipped in as you would like, then you may want another style cleat with a larger connection area and stiffer soled shoes.

Comment: I love my mountain bike cleats because I can walk around in them, and they just look like a pair of running shoes.  The problem is: they don't have a very tight fit with the clips.  And that is OK, but now that I need new pedals I would like to upgrade to something a little more sturdy.  And from what I've heard road bike clips are more sturdy.

Comment: Have you tried to adjust the tension on your existing pedals to give you a firmer interface?

Comment: Yeah, I've been doing that for a while, and now they're as tight as they can go.  But It's not only the tension, the actual pedals are really loud (I've lubed then a few times but it doesn't help).